# Alamofire send array with multiform data

Tags: ios, alamofire

Code:

```
 var arrType = ["first", "second","thrird"]


   upload(
            .POST,
            urlString,
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: strDescription.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name:"business_description")    
                for (var i = 0; i < arrType.count; i++){

                      multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: arrType[i].dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name:"vehicle_types[]")
                } 
            },
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in

                        print("A JSON Result :\(response.result.value)")
                        if let JSON = response.result.value
                        {
                            print("A JSON Result :\(JSON)")
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            print("A JSON parsing error occurred, here are the details: %@" ,response.result.error)
                            delegate.API_CALLBACK_Error(0,errorMessage:c_Server_error)
                        }
                    }
                case .Failure( _):
                    break
                }
        })
```

I try to send an array through multiform data.
when try to execute this code getting failure response from server
is it correct way of sending array with multiform data?
any help will be appreicated.thanks in advance

Comment: In case of failure, what's the error ?

Comment: getting error as One or moreType is not valid

Comment: there's nothing wrong with what you're doing, but it really depends what your server is expecting. Now you're sending unnamed parameters into the `vehicle_types` array, but maybe your server is expecting named parameters? (`vehicle_types['name1']`) You need to check with your back-end developer what he's expecting.

Comment: @dirkgroten thanks for reply

Comment: Find the answer her

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51260292/how-to-append-array-in-multipart-form-data-with-alamofire

2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360413/how-to-send-array-in-params-using-alamofire-multipart/53776415#53776415