# Alamofire.uploadmultipartFormData with JSONEncoding.default (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

i have to send photo and json to server.
my json  is :

```
{"anticorona":"Anti_Covid","time":"Time","navigateds":[{"collection_public_key":"Origin_Station.collection_public_key","station_public_key":"Origin_Station.public_key"},{"station_public_key":"Des_Station.public_key","collection_public_key":"Des_Station.collection_public_key"}],"seats":"Seats","date":"Date"}
```

how can i send this json with Alamofire.uploadmultipartFormData
i know i can use encoding: JSONEncoding.default in Alamofire.request but can in use JSONEncoding.default when use  Alamofire.uploadmultipartFormData?

thanks

Comment: Remove this default json encoding from request as it is not for data request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be new and it would be nice if you could perhaps add some code you have tried in future questions of yours. Anyways, as far as I can see this should be possible in the following way. I am assuming the key `"navigateds"` remains the same. Otherwise you could also check if the value (in the for-in-loop) is an array, too:

```
// set parameters for request
let antiCoronaParameters: Parameters = [
    "anticorona"   : "Anti_Covid",
    "time":"Time",
    "navigateds":[
      ["collection_public_key":"Origin_Station.collection_public_key", "station_public_key":"Origin_Station.public_key"],
      ["station_public_key":"Des_Station.public_key", "collection_public_key":"Des_Station.collection_public_key"]
    ],
    "seats":"Seats",
    "date":"Date"
]

let upload = AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (formData) in

    // I would append file data here first
    
    for (key, value) in antiCoronaParameters {
        if key == "navigateds" {
            do {
                let arrayData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value, options: .prettyPrinted)
                formData.append(arrayData, withName: key)
            } catch {
                print("could not append array, failed with error:", error)
            }
        } else if let string = value as? String, let stringData = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) {
            formData.append(stringData, withName: key)
        } else {
            print("could not append some data in parameters")
        }
    }
    
}, to: "https://www.yourURLhere.com/link.php", method: .post).validate()

upload.responseString { (responseString) in
    print(responseString)
}
```

This answer is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53776554/6022580) question. In the future, I would recommend trying lots of keywords relating to your question. Initially, searching for questions will consume more time but you will get the hang of it soon enough I'm sure. Just keep trying a little more next time maybe ;)

However, as you already mentioned there's another way, too, and I prepared it for you if you would like to check it out. You essentially mentioned it already and I'd always prefer it over the `upload` unless there's a very good reason:

```
// set parameters for request
let antiCoronaParameters: Parameters = [
    "anticorona"   : "Anti_Covid",
    "time":"Time",
    "navigateds":[
      ["collection_public_key":"Origin_Station.collection_public_key", "station_public_key":"Origin_Station.public_key"],
      ["station_public_key":"Des_Station.public_key", "collection_public_key":"Des_Station.collection_public_key"]
    ],
    "seats":"Seats",
    "date":"Date"
]

// request with json encoded parameters (e.g. sending to php)
let antiCoronaRequest = AF.request("https://www.yourURLhere.com/link.php", method: .post, parameters: antiCoronaParameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).validate()
    
antiCoronaRequest.responseString(completionHandler: { (response) in
    print(response)
})
```

Hit me up if you have any questions.