# how to pass arrays in post-request using alamofire 5 swift 5

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, post, alamofire

Im using multipartFormData to post my data using Alamofire.
my API file consist these parameters

```
file location_image
string time
string check_in_frequency
emergency_contacts (sample array=>{[0]=>12, [1]=>13})
```

i have completed string and file part but stuck at arrays.
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

```
multipartFormData.append(self.meetPlacePhoto.image!.pngData()!, withName: "location_image", fileName: "Profile.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
multipartFormData.append("\(self.timeTF.text!)".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "time")
```

please guide me for that arrays to pass in multipartFormData.

Comment: As an aside, a general best practice is to replace those forced unwrappings (!) with conditional optional guards.

Comment: See here for an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360413/how-to-send-array-in-params-using-alamofire-multipart